# Checking Hard Disk Health on HP P410 RAID Card

Tags: centos5, hp, hp-proliant, hardware-raid, hp-smart-array

How can I regularly check health of HDDs on a HP DL180 with P410 RAID Card on a live system?

hpacucli is installed, however, could not see any options for this feature.

Using CentOS, 64-bit.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check the status of the drives manually, look at the front of the server and examine the disk LEDs. The disks LEDs go amber or red when there's a failure.

To check via the Smart Array RAID controller's `hpacucli` utility, you can run:

```
hpacucli ctrl all show config
```

or

```
hpacucli ctrl all show config detail
```

Either can be incorporated into a script as the output looks like:

```
# hpacucli ctrl all show config

Smart Array P410i in Slot 0 (Embedded)    (sn: 50123456789ABCDE)

   array A (SAS, Unused Space: 0 MB)

      logicaldrive 1 (1.6 TB, RAID 1+0, OK)

      physicaldrive 1I:1:1 (port 1I:box 1:bay 1, SAS, 600.1 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:2 (port 1I:box 1:bay 2, SAS, 600.1 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:3 (port 1I:box 1:bay 3, SAS, 600.1 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:4 (port 1I:box 1:bay 4, SAS, 600.1 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 2I:1:5 (port 2I:box 1:bay 5, SAS, 600.1 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 2I:1:6 (port 2I:box 1:bay 6, SAS, 600.1 GB, OK)
```

---

To have continuous monitoring of the system health, you'll want to install the HP Management Agents on the system. This can either be installed whole using the [**HP Service Pack for ProLiant bootable DVD**](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/servers/management/spp/index.html) or piecemeal using the links below.

I'm assuming this is an [**HP ProLiant DL180 G6**](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13248_na/13248_na.HTML) running CentOS 5.

All drivers and agents for this system are [located here](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdHome/?sp4ts.oid=3884340&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=swEnvOID%253D4004%257CswLang%253D%257Caction%253DlistDriver&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken).

What you'll need at a minimum are:

- **[HP SNMP agents](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=3884340&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=idx%253D%257CswItem%253DMTX_d17ad6fb74444cf394977a9471%257CswEnvOID%253D4004%257CitemLocale%253D%257CswLang%253D%257Cmode%253D%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken)**. These monitor the server health and can be configured to send SNMP traps and/or email when there's an event.
- **[HP System CLI Utilities](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=3884340&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=idx%253D%257CswItem%253DMTX_21480855dab14b59a8c616d203%257CswEnvOID%253D4004%257CitemLocale%253D%257CswLang%253D%257Cmode%253D%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken)**. These provide CLI utilities for system health reporting, the server's UID light and the ability to view the IML system event log.
- *optional* - [**HP System Management Homepage**](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=3884340&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=idx%253D%257CswItem%253DMTX_495c636c3e5c4caca9bdcdba1d%257CswEnvOID%253D4004%257CitemLocale%253D%257CswLang%253D%257Cmode%253D%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken). This is a web-based system console that shows overall server health.

Comment: Thanks, the information has been useful and I am using it.

Will the results give valid information on the health of SSD drives?

Comment: @John Yes, if the drive has failed or not.